# Convert mysql timestamp to date in codeigniter query object for us in csv_from_result method

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date, time

I've got the following code:

```
$query = $this->EE->db->select('*')->where('form_name', 'Newsletter')->get('freeform_entries');
        $filename = "newsletter.csv";
        $path = "some/path";
        $delimiter = ",";
        $newline = "\r\n";
        $csv_data = $this->EE->dbutil->csv_from_result($query, $delimiter, $newline);
```

But one of those fields is a timestamp and i need to convert it to date time so that when output to csv that is how it looks. so i need 20-10-13 09:28 rather than 1357752502

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FROM_UNIXTIME** returns a representation of the unix_timestamp argument as a value in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS':

```
$query = $this->EE->db->select('FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp_field) AS "value"', ... )->where('form_name', 'Newsletter')->get('freeform_entries');
        $filename = "newsletter.csv";
        $path = "some/path";
        $delimiter = ",";
        $newline = "\r\n";
        $csv_data = $this->EE->dbutil->csv_from_result($query, $delimiter, $newline);
```

Further info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

Comment: Just one quick question, in here: 'FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp_field) AS "value"', ... ) how do i say: and all other fields i.e a * as well?

Comment: Oh it's ok, ignore that, i had a typo but was doing it right. Thanks again!!